# ionic 3 angular background image not appearing

Tags: iphone, css, angular, ionic3

i am having a ionic 3 angular app and using the background as follows:

**app.scss**

```
ion-content{
    background-image: url('/assets/images/dummy_bg.jpg');
}
```

this works fine when i see it in desktop browser. however, it does not render the background image on the iphone when i deploy it.

what could be the issue? i have made sure the size for my iphone 7 plus is 1242*2208

do i need to do something else to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to execute in server because of path problem :

```
 background-image: url('assets/images/dummy_bg.jpg'); 
or
 background-image: url('../assets/images/dummy_bg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the forward slash in the url:

```
background-image: url('assets/images/dummy_bg.jpg');
```